# Mongoose aggregate Not Error: not showing a specific episode of specific season tv and does not populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'd like to know what is wrong with the code, why the code doesn't work.

I like a output like this:

```
      {
        "seasons":
        [{

      "_id": "dhuhuasuhru8484r9r9ur",
      "number": 2,
    "year": 2009,

       "episodes": [{
                     //only the specific episode, if I type 5 in the url, I must receive 5th episode 
                   and not all episodes

                 "id": "ruuhjbrrjrur9f887f88fds898",
                  "title": "universal stone",
                  "number": 5,
                  "releasedOn": "2009-11-05T16:30:00.002Z",
                  "description": "Us"
                             "cast": [{
                                  "_id":"jfsijfju8u435ju35uh",
                                   "fullName":"Joseph Sherlington",
                                    "birthDate": "2012-02-10T15:00:00",
                                    "genre":"male",
                                     "nationality":"french"
                                  },
                                       {
                                        "_id":"uhhgb545h4nhhyuh",
                                        "fullName":"Mathhiias toryn",
                                        "birthDate": "2012-05-10T16:00:00",
                                        "genre": "male",
                                        "nationality":"german"

                                              }],
                                  "director":{
                                         "_id":"hjrhbh4h443h4h",
                                          "fullName": "Alexis Sanders",
                                          "nationality": "american"


                                            }


                                              }]
                                             }

                                           ]}
```

This is my tv show routes.js:

```
             router.get("/showid/:tvShowId/episodenumber", tvShowsCtrl.getTvShowEpisode);
```

the model:

```
              const tvShowSchema = new Schema({

                           name: String,

                            year: Number,

                            country: String,

                                    seasons: [{

                                       number: Number,

                                       year: Number,

                                          episodes:[{
                                              title: String,

                                              number: Number,

                                              releasedOn: Date,

                                              description: String,
 
                                                     cast:[
                                                       {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                                                            ref:'actors'
                                                                }],

                                                          director:{
                                                                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                                                                ref:'directors'
                                                                 }


                                                            },

                                                    {timeStamps: true,

                                                     versionKey: false

                                                           }

                                                              ]

                                                              }]

                                                      });
```

This is the tv show controller method when does not populate nor showing specific episode from specific season. I use in url one id and queries to avoid duplicate ids:

```
                   export const getTvShowEpisode = async(req,res) =>{

                           try{

                            const { tvShowId } = req.params;

                            const { seasonId } = req.params;

                            const { episodeId } = req.params;


                             let selectedEpisode = null;
    
                                 const tvShowEpisode = await TVShow.aggregate([
            
            

                                      { $match:{

                                          "_id": Types.ObjectId(tvShowId),
                                          /* "seasons._id": Types.ObjectId(seasonId),
                                          "seasons.episodes._id": Types.ObjectId(episodeId),*/
                                          "seasons.number": req.query.seasonnumber,
                                          "seasons.episodes.number": req.query.number,
            
                                              }},

                                 // Does not populate

                         {$lookup: {from:'actors', localField: 'seasons.episodes.cast', foreignField: 
                         '_id', as: 'actors'}
                           },
                           //Does not populate

                            {$lookup: {from:'directors', localField: 'seasons.episodes.director', 
                             foreignField: '_id', as: 'director'}}, 

                                  {$unwind: '$seasons'},  

                               {$match: {"seasons._id": Types.ObjectId(seasonId)}}, 
                        {$project: {"_id": Types.ObjectId(tvShowId),"episode": "$seasons.episodes"}},
      
                                  ]);

                                   if (tvShowEpisode) {
                                       res.send(tvShowEpisode);
                                       } else {
                                           res
                                           .status(404)
                                      .send({ mensaje: `tv show episode not found` });
                                           }

                                              }
                                         catch(error){
                                             console.log(error);
                                         res.status(500).send({message: `error: \n\n${error}`});
                                           }

                                 };
```

The real output I've got on postman is although "200 OK Status", it returns is empty and do not populate actors nor director.

I'd like to know what could I do. There isn't error message of console.log(err).

What is wrong?